# Recursion in angular directives / templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to build a custom directive for displaying a tree. For some reason it seems that once you include the directive in its own template, something runs wild in the angular compiler and the browser process gets stuck in a loop.
Here's a plunker:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
<a ng-click="clicked(item)"><span ng-if="item.items" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus text-primary"></span></a>
<span ng-if="!item.items" class="glyphicon glyphicon-record text-primary"></span>
<a>{{item.name}}</a>
<div ng-if="item.items && item.items.length>0">
    <ul class="list-group"> 
        <taxonomy-item ng-if="item.items && item.items.length>0" ng-repeat="child in item.items"></taxonomy-item>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you pay attention you'll see that it doesn't even bind data, so it shouldn't be a recursive loop caused by model/data, but rather a compiler issue...

http://plnkr.co/edit/1aollcuCr2gA96W6Sk6q

***Careful, running might freeze your browser tab!***

Any suggestions on how to work around this problem?

Comment: Post the code for the directive in the questiion. Why are you nesting identical `ng-if`?

Comment: There's code on plunker, what's the point of posting dozens of lines of code into the question? There's a nested if because I was messing around, trying to see whether it's the element itself that causes the issue.

Comment: So I should go have browser lock up just to read your code .... in order to try to help you? Wrong! Also, questions should be self contained, that's how SO works. We shouldn't have to go to an external site to review the problematic code

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that you cannot use a directive within it's own template.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wasn't aware that it's not supported. Classic case of tl;dr

Comment: Adding link to zeroflagL's comment - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. Since angular doesn't permit the usage of directives within themselves, you need to make use of the ***link*** function, to add the child directive afterwards. A minimal example:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", ["$compile",function($compile){

    var template = '<my-directive ng-repeat="child in item.items" ng-model="child"></my-directive>';

    return{
        templateUrl: "myDirective.html",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            item: "=ngModel"    
        },
        link: function(scope, element){                     
            var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
            element.append(compiled);
        }
    }   
}]);
```

This won't cause any trouble, since the compiled child directive is self-contained and compiled afterwards.